# How do I increase the Heap Size for FreeRTOS in Zynq702 SoC?

Tags: memory-management, embedded-linux, zynq, soc, petalinux

I am using **Zynq** 702 SoC. It has 2 CPU's. CPU0 is loaded with Petalinux and Cpu1 with FreeRtos and my FreeRtos current heap Size is 6MB.

The actual size of the RAM is 1GB, in this 512MB being set in the Petalinux Kernel and rest is not used and want to use completely for CPU1. I am using OpenAMP for communications between 2cores.

I want to increase the Heap size of FreeRtos so that this new Heap size will help us in developing some more features.

Is anybody tried to include OpenAMP and for loading CPU1, and the stack can be expanded to > 16MB.

Answer (score 0):

FreeRTOS has more than one heap implementation - and in fact can be used with no heap at all - how the heap is increased depends on which implementation is in use.  See https://www.freertos.org/a00111.html for details.